# Speedy Acceptance of Answers

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accepted-answer

I strongly agree with those who say that answer acceptance is solely in the domain of the questioner.

That said...

Some other stack exchange sites have a culture which strongly encourages accepting answers after a few folks have had an opportunity to answer. For an example, see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/how-can-we-encourage-people-to-wait-before-accepting-answers. In part,

> Increasingly, we are seeing question askers wait only a matter of hours before accepting an answer.

Is speedy acceptance (FGITW may be related?) something that needs to be addressed or discussed for Stack Overflow? Should a slower limit of answer acceptance (currently 15 minutes) be imposed? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder what the stats actually are on this. That is, what percentage of answers are accepted within, say, the first 30 minutes of question creation?

Comment: SEDE to the rescue (maybe...), time to tinker

Comment: @theB about 50%.  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/499363/632353/ratio-answers-accepted-withtin-30-minutes-over-questions-with-accepted-answers

Comment: Its worth noting that on SO, many answerers bug the asker to accept their answer asap. Many askers consequently either accept an answer quickly (to shut the answerer up) or don't at all.

Comment: I wonder what `speedy acceptance` means for you. `only a matter of hours` seems a long long time to me. Moreover, if an answer satisfies your needs after one minute... what do you wait for? accept it and remove that post from the Unanswered Question Queue as soon as possible!

Comment: I think it would probably be wise, to allow for a quick tentative acceptance (not the green check mark) -- that does not yet provide the credit, that can be changed to new superior answers if they show up. The tentatively accepted answer delayed to "firm up" to the official accepted answer (green checkmark) until not before one 24 hour period has passed.

Comment: The idea of having a single accepted answer is not at all in keeping with the goals of Stack Exchange and it should be scrapped altogether. The answer that the OP found most helpful adds nothing for other users that the voting system doesnt already provide. Like all other users the OP should +1 on any of the answers which were useful to them

Comment: @LonnieZamora A couple of hours is not enough for eveyrone to even see the question (just think about Timezones...). So if you accept an answer too fast, you might miss the opportunity of someone else giving a better explained/researched answer...

Comment: You don't miss anything. You can undo your acceptance and accept another answer, if you think it's a better one.

Comment: @LonnieZamora  Except many people (myself at least) won't bother reading a question that already has an accepted answer.

Comment: Simple fix: just get rid of the accepted answer and instead allow the OP to be able to up vote answers on their question regardless of current rep.  Fixes other problems as well like the accepted answer may not be the best but it is pinned to the top.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Yeah, perhaps. My only gripe with that is that about the only "fun" left in this "game" is getting as many accepts as possible to beat the daily repcap ;)

Comment: You should wait six to eight units of time (weeks seems long). :)

Comment: @Joel I agree.  It's a waste of time to keep going back to answer questions where the OP has already had their problem solved.  And, the challenge is to find a tough one where you can really help.  Now, if I am having a related problem and find a question that needs more information, I'm glad to help.

Comment: Overall, I'd like to see the forum provide some encouragement to have the OP accept an answer, and I understand that it is frowned upon for someone providing answers to do that.  But, when I am looking for help, I want to know what worked for the OP and it's annoying not to have that information, even if the OP needs to provide it.

Comment: @oldtechaa six to eight weeks is the exact amount of time anything could, should, and would take to complete. Even if it's brushing your teeth or building the Great Wall.

Comment: Old hands will remember the '%accepted' statistic which reported the percentage of their own questions for which a user had accepted an answer.  It was gotten rid of quite a while ago because it got misused as a stick to 'force' people into accepting answers.  I still think it had uses — it would set your expectation on whether any answer would ever be accepted — but apparently the misuse was worse than the use.

Comment: Just as long as an answer eventually *is* accepted, or the asker at least occasionally checks back in to comment on what's missing from what exists. What I hate are orphaned, often legitimately answered, questions that make tag queues look like there are many questions still open. Some way to provisionally mark an answer as accepted (eg, anything with three votes and no OP activity for X months) would be great.

Comment: @A.Danischewski The OP can unaccept an answer and accept a different answer - I don't see what the difference in end result would be here.

Comment: @rdans The rep gained from your answer being chosen by the asker as the one that helped them solve their specific issue is very nice. And as an answerer, I like seeing that the question is resolved, so I don't need to try to provide another answer. As someone who is coming from a google search, I would still like to see which answer the asker found most useful for their question (assuming I'm having the same issue as the asker), so I feel like your statement of *'The answer that the OP found most helpful adds nothing for other users'* is just wrong.

Comment: @Macro Man -- It may seem rude to some people to provide them with points and credit only to later take it away from them. If you allow them to select an tentative answer yet leave it pending without points transferred for a short period (e.g. 24hr) - then changing the selected answer will likely be more warmly embraced.

Comment: @Zack I used to do the same thing and look at the accepted answer first but now I know a bit more about Stack Overflow I realise that the most up-voted answer is usually the best one. so I think this is misleading for people who find answers from Google. To a casual user, the green tick adds some legitimacy to the answer even though there might a very much more correct one just underneath being endorsed by every other stack overflow user. If the accepted answer has one upvote and another answer has 100 upvotes then we shouldn't be telling people that the 1 upvoted answer is the correct one.

Comment: @rdans So what do you suggest to happen if the accepted answer has less votes than a different answer? I don't feel like people upvoting an answer necessarily means that it was the best answer for the asker's specific question, that is what the "accepted answer" is supposed to point out. I don't think there is anything wrong with the current system because like you said you can just look at other answers to see if something other than the accepted answer works better for *your* situation.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The "perfect" answer acceptance waiting period for one question might be way too short or long for other questions that have a different level of complexity. When the system imposes a minimum time that minimum has to be a compromise intended to be reasonable for *most* questions. Is fifteen minutes reasonable for most? I'm not sure, but it is reasonable for some.

Even if an accepted answer is perfectly correct, it is possible that a complicated concept could be explained in several different ways that each provides an "aha" moment of understanding to different readers, so it would be nice to wait to see if other explanations are forthcoming.

Also, it's disappointing when the OP accepts an answer that is demonstrably wrong or incomplete, especially when other answers already posted are better.

But of course not all Stack Overflow questions are about complex concepts. Often the OP's code just has a couple of simple syntax errors or typos that are immediately obvious to experienced programmers. In those cases, sometimes it only takes a fairly short answer to explain clearly what the error is and how to fix it, such that subsequent answers couldn't possibly expand upon that in any meaningful way - so why shouldn't such an answer be accepted immediately?

Anyway, presumably the people asking questions are reasonably happy with the answers they accept, so if they were prevented from accepting until later there's a good chance they wouldn't actually come back later, at least, not until they want to ask another question.

Comment: " Often the OP's code just has a couple of simple syntax errors or typos [...]." In that case, they are *off-topic*, and the whole question should be closed or deleted. Other than that, you are absolutely right, there is no universal "best" time limit.

Comment: @Polygnome "Other than that, you are absolutely right, there is no universal 'best' time limit." So.... 20 minutes? ;)

Comment: @Polygnome Perhaps he meant to say "bugs"? As in, this code compiles, I'm trying to implement A but I'm observing B.

Comment: *“it's disappointing when the OP accepts an answer that is demonstrably wrong or incomplete, especially when other answers already posted are better.”* This! I'm really wondering whether it's that useful to have an accepted answer, rather than a "mark answered" as the question level. As other have pointed out, there are often more than one good answer.

Comment: If the answer is demonstrably wrong (and isn't corrected) then it's the community's job to downvote it into oblivion, whilst upvoting the correct answer.

Comment: @MicroVirus - You can't downvote an accepted answer into oblivion if it's pinned to the top.

Comment: I've answered questions months after they were posted and ended up with the accepted answer on occasion. If none of the answers offered are good enough to solve someone's issue, it seems wrong for the people who have answered to expect an accept, rather than allowing the question to be answered effectively.

Answer (score 23):

Stack Overflow has a user base many, many times that of other Stack Exchange sites.

On SO, you are likely to get more distinct eyes on your problem in the first 6 minutes than other sites can get in hours.

It can lead to FGITW, where someone quickly whips up a solution to the problem that is mediocre, which gets upvotes (for being correct) and accepted, while someone writing a slower yet better answer is left in the dust.

But I personally have answered a question 4 hours after the top answer.  It had the checkmark, and I believe had 20+ votes.  The checkmarked answer was also correct in technical detail and in presentation.  So it wasn't a case of "no, you are wrong", but simply "I can word that better".

The OP and other voters on the question agreed (mainly the OP actually: I think my answer was 3rd or 4th when the checkmark moved).  It got the check, and eventually votes.

Checkmarks are not irrevocable.  Some of my highest "point" answers were on questions where the checked answer was obsolete or could be improved, ranging from minutes to hours to (in at least one case) [years](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/1774667) behind the acceptance of the original answer.

It doesn't always work.  Sometimes the OP doesn't feel right about moving the check, or disagrees with how awesome your answer is.  Sometimes the OP is long gone, and even if your answer is Hamilton-calibre you won't get the checkmark.  But delayed checkmarks don't fix that either; it would just mean no answer has the check.

It is true that it can take hours before a particular person or time zone sees your answer.  But this is SO, there: there are very very few questions where only one person knows the answer to a given problem, or could write up a quality answer to it.

I'm not seeing a serious problem.  Maybe on low-traffic tags the 15 minute window is too tight, but a blanket change is not justified.

Comment: I was going to write an answer here, but you said everything I was thinking. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, Burr eventually *did* give Hamilton the checkmark.

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly legitimate for an answer to be correct (and accepted as such), only to later have another answer be *better* (e.g. more efficient, or clearer).

If an asker gets a better answer it's perfectly legitimate to **un-accept and accept the better one**, in fact it should be encouraged!

That can happen months or even years later. There's a [silver badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) for answering 60 days after the question was asked (and getting +5).

*I've answered a question **two years** after it was asked, it's not accepted but it now has more upvotes that the accepted answer. Of course, I answered this because I had the same question and was not satisfied with any of the existing answers. My point is: even if the limit were increased it still wouldn't catch all.*

---

#### In defense of 15 minutes:

- 15 minutes is enough to write a solid answer to most questions.
- If you receive an answer in that time that solves your problem (and satisfies you), accepting should be encouraged (by the system).
- Askers should stick around for a while e.g to clarify their question. The 15 minute wait, kinda forces them to do that (if they want the +2)... if it's much longer it means they'll have to accept in their next session (so why hang around?).
- Mitigates accepting the first *junk* answer, that may be enough to convince the OP but would be downvoted by anyone else reading (after downvoting the OP will be less lightly to accept).

I suspect that increasing it beyond 15 minutes would only mean fewer accepts.

*That said, whether this should be configurable for other sites is a different question.*

Comment: "15 minutes is enough to write a solid answer to most questions." is true except when does the clock start?  15 minutes is enough time from when I first see it, yet I may not see the post for hours after the OP formed it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to impose a time limit of any kind.

An answer being accepted is purely down to the OP, and if the answer solves their issue then no-one else can decide that.

If a better answer then comes up, well that's what we have vote buttons for. Many a time I've landed on a page where an answer has 3 or 4 times the amount of votes than the accepted answer. In this case it's pretty obvious which is the best answer.

The 15 points from the accepted answer is to reward the answerer for helping the OP with whatever the issue may be, not necessarily for having 'the best' answer.

In summary, I think we need to stop focusing on that green tick and use the voting system for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

> Should a slower limit of answer acceptance (currently 15 minutes) be imposed? Or something else entirely?

Perhaps a posted self-imposed minimum time limit, set by the OP on that post, would help?

Presently this is 15 minutes per SO rules.  Yet if an OP's post said 1 hour or 1 day then the SO community knows the urgency versus quality need.

I would welcome knowing an OP was willing to wait a day before accepting as that would encourage me (and I suspect others) to form higher quality answers.

Filtering questions could include "those still within the initial OP allotted time".

---

If this option is viewed as "yet another" feature and over-complicates things, consider if a post or user profile included the OP's median accept time. I am much more inclined to help those who are thoughtful in their reviews/acceptances versus "give me the answer ASAP" crowd.